# parse error when i use Z3_parse_smtlib2_file to parse example files provided in Z3

Tags: api, z3, parse-error

I am using Z3 4.1 and I want to parse smt lib2 format inputs in my program.

So I firstly try to use `Z3_parse_smtlib2_file` to parse the examples provided in Z3 (located under folder Z3-4.1/examples/smtlib). But I find many parse errors and then my program exits immediately. I think the input format should be right. I try to parse Z3.2.smt2 by using the following code:

```
(set-option :auto-config true)
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-const a Int)
(declare-fun f (Int Bool) Int)
(assert (> a 10))
(assert (< (f a true) 100))
(check-sat)
```

The result is the following :

```
smt2parser_example
(error "line 1 column 26: error setting ':auto-config', option value cannot be modified after initialization")
Error code: 4
BUG: incorrect use of Z3.
```

The API is invoked like this :

```
fs = Z3_parse_smtlib2_file(ctx, fname, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Where is the problem ? The input file should be OK. Is the problem lying in the arguments in Z3_parse_smtlib2_file ?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the error message, the auto-config option cannot be modified once the Z3 context is initialized. Only a few options are mutable and can be changed after the context is created and auto-config is not among them. 
When the line

```
(set-option :auto-config true)
```

is removed from the input file it parses correctly. If your application requires any options to be set, it would be best to pass them to the context constructor directly, i.e., by passing a `config` (in C++) or `Z3_config` (in C) object to it.

Comment: Christoph, you are right. The parser API works well when I remove the line "(set-option :auto-config true)". But I run into a new problem. Z3_parse_smtlib2_file produces error when I add a new line "(get-model)" in the end of the input file. The error message is: smt2parser_example
(error "line 9 column 10: model is not available")
Error code: 4
BUG: incorrect use of Z3.

Comment: Indeed, that's the case for me too. The :produce-models option is ignored here, it should be set when constructing the context. Generally, the parsing functions Z3_parse_smtlib* are mainly intended for parsing formulas. SMT2 scripts can be executed directly on the command line by passing them to the Z3 binary.